# Microsoft Outlook 365 pastes images large images from Snipping Tool

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images, snipping

[image: Enlarged image from Snipping Tool]

Copying any image from the default "Snipping Tool" (via Ctrl+C) and pasting into MS Outlook 365 (via Ctrl+V) results in a super-large image being displayed.

The instructions here did not work (https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/31833-snipping-tool-image-too-big.html):

```
Sounds like it's stretching the image to fit the screen. Go into
Settings, then Personalization and select Center under Choose a Fit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer; but in my case if I change the DPI scaling from 200% to 100% the problem goes away.  I am running a Surface Book with a very high resolution so changing the DPI scaling is not really a good option for me.

It seems that when pasting the image windows is not taking into account this setting.